# Returning JSON data from PHP file using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

Long time reader, first time poster. I'm very new to the world of jQuery and JSON and have been seeing an issue with a login script I'm running.

The end goal is to capture data from a form, pass that data to a PHP file for processing via jQuery.ajax() post, compare the data against a MySQL database for authentication and return a data for either a success of failure.

My problem is that I cannot get the JSON formatted data to be passed from the PHP script back to the jQuery. When viewing the processing with Chrome's Developer Tools, I see that 'Login Failure'. I've double checked the array $rows by throwing it to my error_log file and it returns properly formatted JSON, but I just can't for the life of me get it to return to the jQuery file. Any help is appreciated.

**My form input:**

```
<!-- BEGIN: Login Page -->
    <section data-role="page" id="login">
        <header data-role="header" data-theme="b">
            <a href="#landing" class="ui-btn-left">Back</a>
        <h1>Please Log In</h1>
        </header>
        <div data-role="content" class="content" data-theme="b">
            <form id="loginForm" action="services.php" method="post">
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="schoolID">School ID</label>
                    <input type="text" name="schoolID" id="schoolID" value=""  />

                    <label for="userName">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" value=""  />

                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value=""  />

                    <h3 id="notification"></h3>
                    <button data-theme="b" id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="loginForm" id="action">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
            <h1>Footer</h1>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- END: Login Page -->
```

**My jQuery Handler:**

```
// Listen for the the submit button is clicked, serialize the data and send it off
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        var data = $("#loginForm :input").serializeArray();
    var url = $("#loginForm").attr('action');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        cache: false,
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: "services.php",
                success: function(json){
                alert(json);
                $('#notification').append(json);
                }
            });
            }
        });
    });
```

**And here is my PHP processing:**

```
if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
    $schoolID = $_POST['schoolID'];
    $userName = $_POST['userName'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $sql = "SELECT FirstName, LastName, FamilyID, StudentID, UserID ";
    $sql .= "FROM Users ";
    $sql .= "WHERE SchoolID = '$schoolID' ";
    $sql .= "AND Username = '$userName' ";
    $sql .= "AND Password = '$password'";
    $rs = mysql_query($sql);

    $rows = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $row_array['firstName'] = $row['FirstName'];
        $row_array['lastName'] = $row['LastName'];
        $row_array['familyID'] = $row['FamilyID'];
        $row_array['studentID'] = $row['StudentID'];
        $row_array['userID'] = $row['UserID'];
        array_push($rows, $row_array);
    }

    header("Content-type: application/json", true);
    echo json_encode(array('rows'=>$rows));
    exit;

    }else{

    echo "Login Failure";
    }
```

Comment: "pass that data to a PHP file for processing via jQuery" jQuery runs on the client. PHP runs on the server. They never meet.

Comment: I'm using the $.ajax() function in jQuery to pass JSON data to the PHP. I'm sorry, I didn't explain it very well.

Comment: the problem I think may be that you are making 2 requests the first perhaps responds with the data you want which you don't process the second with the data you don't as the condition in your php is never met, also look into using [.submit()](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) - [tut](http://www.ryancoughlin.com/2008/11/04/use-jquery-to-submit-form/) maybe the condition is never met?

Comment: Why do you need to do 2 ajax calls? In this case, why do do you show only 1 php script, not 2?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's correct, but from what I've gathering I have to use $.ajax() to POST the serlialized data and then in the success function for that, $.ajax() to GET the JSON data. I have a sneaking suspicion that I am terribly wrong in that assumption though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look what mistake you are making here it is very simple

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'services.php',
    cache: false,
    data: $('#loginForm').serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
            $('#notification').append(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Use serialize function of jquery. And when you have a parameter in success function it is not that 'data' you have in this instruction

```
data : data,
```

It is returned from php end it is new data returned on success. To avoid confliction use some thing else like new_data

```
    success: function(new_data){
        alert(new_data);
        $('#notification').append(new_data);
    }
```

New data is in json format check it. Use console.log to see in firebug if you are using firefox.

```
    success: function(new_data){
        console.log(new_data);
        alert(new_data);
        $('#notification').append(new_data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
var data = $("#loginForm :input").serializeArray();
```

to:

```
var data = $("#loginForm").serialize();
```

This should work as I'm pretty sure "data" in the .ajax request is supposed to be a serialized string, serializeArray returns an array of objects.

http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

EDIT 1:

This looks like an event bubbling problem. Try the following:

Change your javascript to:

```
function processForm(formObj) {
    var $form = $(formObj);
    var data = $form.serializeArray();
    var url = $form).attr('action');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        cache: false,
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            $('#notification').append(data);
        }
    });

    return false;
}
```

And your form to:

```
<form id="loginForm" action="services.php" method="post" onsubmit="return processForm(this)">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="schoolID">School ID</label>
        <input type="text" name="schoolID" id="schoolID" value=""  />

        <label for="userName">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" value=""  />

        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value=""  />

        <h3 id="notification"></h3>
        <button data-theme="b" id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="loginForm" id="action">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I changed the data variable but the PHP script is still sending over 'Login Failure'. Even though the PHP error_log reads {"rows":[{"firstName":"Zach","lastName":"Alexander","familyID":"0","studentID":"0","userID":"87585"}]}

Comment: @Sharproot - If it is returning `Login Failure`, then it shouldn't have queried the database based on the php code you gave us. The change suggested by Garry Welding won't make a difference here, however it does make more sense and is more readable than the code you were using in it's place.

Comment: Yes, I agree that @Garry Welding's change makes much more sense.  That is why I'm so confused. All the PHP code is in an if() statement where if $_POST is set we compare and encode and if it's not set we get 'Login Failure'. But by monitoring my error_logs, I can see that the PHP is processing and getting the correct data back from the database...but we still end up getting the 'Login Failure'.

Comment: try what's suggested in EDIT 1: above, looks like you have the click event on the submit function firing first, and then because the button is a submit button your getting the form submitting manually too. The events are bubbling through the DOM. You could also keep your code the same and just use event.stopPropagation(); to stop the bubble.

Comment: this would also explain why you get the error log data, as the ajax request is firing first, but then the warning because the default event (form submission) is firing next. This is why I always use onsubmit rather than binding a click handler to the submit button.

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone. It seems as if I just simply didn't understand that the getJSON() also handled the retrieving of data. I assumed it was one function to send data and one to retrieve it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: user error. I didn't truly understand the concept of the getJSON() function. It is meant to send the data to the PHP script and also handle the return data on success. I assumed that it would require one function to send info and one function to retrieve info.

Thanks for all your help!